# React Query with firebase returns undefined

Tags: next.js, react-query

I am very new to state management libraries and the one that I chose was React Query. I have followed multiple tutorials about it with mock data, but when I try to use my firebase imported data, it returns undefined. I am attaching all of my code with instances of React Query in it. This app is in next js 12.

file where I want to fetch and render data

```
const fetchDbData = async () => {
    const {currentUser} = UseAuth();
    function getLoc() {
        if (currentUser) {
            return 'users/' + currentUser.uid + '/userInvestments'
        } else {
            return 'users/TestDocumentForDatabase/userInvestments'
        };
    }
    const loc = getLoc();
    const q = query(collection(db, loc));
    const snapshot = await getDocs(q);
    console.log(snapshot)
    const {data, status, error} = useQuery(
        ['firebaseData'], 
        () => snapshot.forEach(doc => doc.data()),
        {
            refetchOnWindowFocus: false
        },
        {
            retry: false
        },
    )
    return {data, status, error}
}

export default function usePortfolio() {
    const {data, status, error} = fetchDbData
    .....
```

_app.js

```
export const queryClient = new QueryClient({
  defaultOptions: {
      queries: {
          refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
          useInfiniteQury: false,
      },
  }   
})
export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <AuthProvider >
        <RootLayout>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </RootLayout>
      </AuthProvider>
     
    </QueryClientProvider>
)}
```

Comment: 1. `fetchDbData` looks like a hook, the convention should be `useFetchDbData` and invoking it `useFetchDbData()`.
2. At first, data is `undefined` until it is fetched successfully for the first time

Comment: @MorKadosh when I invoke `useFetchDbData`, would that be inside of the useQuery hook?